# setfield is not working

Tags: matlab, struct

I have `a.b`, a three element vector. I want to change first 2 elements. Code in the third line does not include the change in second line. For instance, second line responds as:

```
[2 0 0]
```

Third line responds as:

```
[0 3 0]
```

My code is as follows.

```
a.b = [0 0 0]
setfield(a,'b',{1},2)
setfield(a,'b',{2},3)
```

This code is an example. It is to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can correct it as

```
a.b = [0 0 0];
a = setfield(a, 'b', {1}, 2);
a = setfield(a, 'b', {2}, 3);
```

From the help of `setfield`:

> S = setfield(S,'field',V) sets the contents of the specified
>       field to the value V.  This is equivalent to the syntax S.field = V.
>       S must be a 1-by-1 structure.  **The changed structure is returned.**

Without capturing the return value, the first `setfield` call will assign the modified `struct` to the `ans` variable.

Therefore the following code also works, but should be avoided:

```
a.b = [0 0 0];
setfield(a, 'b', {1}, 2);
a = setfield(ans, 'b', {2}, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

An bit faster alternativ to **setfield()** would be

> a.b(1:2) = [2 3]

or if the index isn't in a sequence

> a.b([1 3]) = [2 5]

Comment: If you want to do this in a script, it does not work (in a way I don't understand). Thus, I can presume that it won't work.

Comment: It should work fine in a script, but as the code is your question is an example you probably have a more complex struct and the solution has to be tweaked a little.